# Error when I use process.env with Vue and Vite

Tags: firebase, vue.js, environment-variables, vite

I'm coding a web application with Vue, Vue router, Vite and Firebase to handle the auth. To intialize my Firebase application I use the .env and to get the firebase variables (like VUE_APP_API_KEY, VUE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN, etc...) in my `firebase.js` file I use `process.env.VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE`. However when I go to my main page I've got an error in my browser's console.

Here is the error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined at firebase.js:6:13

So I've tried to use `import.meta.env` instead of `process.env` but for all my variables in the  `.env` file, it returns me undefined. I've tried too to define all my variables in the `vite.config.js` like this but it still returns me undefined:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  define: {
    "process.env.VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE": process.env.VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE
  }
})
```

I'm sure that all my variables are indeed declare in the `.env` file because my IDE propose me all the good name with the auto-completion. In doubt I've tried to rename the `.env` file by `.env.local` but it's still the same.

Here is my `firebase.js` file's code:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.VUE_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.VUE_APP_APP_ID
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { auth, db };
```

So can anyone help me to solve my error ?

(PS: I apologize if my English wasn't perfect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only variables prefixed with `VITE_` are exposed. [Source](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files)

Vite uses `import.meta.env`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using React and Vite.

I swapped out

```
apiKey: process.env.PUBLIC_API_KEY,
```

for

```
apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_PUBLIC_API_KEY
```

etc.

Then, I needed to move sure my .env.local file was in my src folder, and rename varaibles in .env.local of course

Comment: what do you mean by
"Then, I needed to move sure my .env.local file was in my src folder, and rename varaibles in .env.local of course"

I'm having the same issue. do you have a .env.local file and did you move it to your src folder? Is it a separate file from the standard .env file? Thanks!